# Is there any solution "Gridview shows only one data after update new entry."?

Tags: c#, gridview

Every time when I click the button only one row will be displayed. But it should show multiple rows. I declare the list after the constructor invoke. I tried with gridview.update() and gridview.refresh() but they didn't work. I could not findout the issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using JournalEntryApp.Model;

namespace JournalEntryApp
{
    public partial class NewDocument : Form
    {
        public NewDocument()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<JEFrom> JEFromsList = new List<JEFrom>();
        List<JETo> JETosList = new List<JETo>();
        JEFrom _jef = null;

        private void NewDocument_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label4.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            using (var db =new JournalContext())
            {
                unitComboBox.DataSource = db.Units.ToList();
                unitComboBox.ValueMember = "Id";
                unitComboBox.DisplayMember = "UnitName";

            }
        }

        private void addToListButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (string.Empty== fromAccountTextBox.Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("From Account can not be empty!!!");
            }
            else if (string.Empty == toAccountTextBox.Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("To Account can not be empty!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                _jef = new JEFrom{ FromEntryName= fromAccountTextBox.Text , FromEntryDate= DateTime.Now };
                JEFromsList.Add(_jef);
                temporaryDataGridView.DataSource = JEFromsList;

                fromAccountTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
                toAccountTextBox.Text = string.Empty;



            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you initialize JEFromsList?

Comment: After the class constructor invoke.

Comment: ```List<JEFrom> JEFromsList = new List<JEFrom>();  
List<JETo> JETosList = new List<JETo>();   
JEFrom _jef = null;```

Comment: can you paste full code, except the ui design codes.

Comment: I already update the code. Pls check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temporaryDataGridView cannot detect that you have changed the DataSource. It will only refresh when Datasource has changed.

```
temporaryDataGridView.DataSource = null;
temporaryDataGridView.DataSource = JEFromsList;
```

so change the Datasource null first.

Or you can use bindingSource

```
private void NewDocument_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.bindingSource1.DataSource = JEFromsList;
    temporaryDataGridView.DataSource = this.bindingSource1;

    label4.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    using (var db =new JournalContext())
    {
        unitComboBox.DataSource = db.Units.ToList();
        unitComboBox.ValueMember = "Id";
        unitComboBox.DisplayMember = "UnitName";
    }
}
```

in button_click

```
JEFromsList.Add(_jef);
bindingSource1.ResetBindings(true);
```